# Problems saving dialog data in OnOK

Tags: c++, mfc

Has anyone found a good way to save dialog data to a database in `CMyDialog::OnOK`?

```
void CMyDialog::OnOK()
{

    // If I save my data here, I don't know if DoDataExchange()
    // found validation errors.

    CDialog::OnOK();

    // If I save my data here, EndDialog() has already been called

}
```

Looking for ideas on how best to structure this. I know the norm is to have the caller save the data as needed but I don't want the dialog to close if I encounter an error saving the data to the database.

It seems like a good solution would be if `CDialog::UpdateData()` were virtual, but it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use [`UpdateData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/t9fb9hww(v=vs.85))?

The return value:

> Nonzero if the operation is successful; otherwise 0. If `bSaveAndValidate` is `TRUE`, then a return value of nonzero **means that the data is successfully validated**.

So:

```
void CMyDialog::OnOK()
{
    if(!UpdateData(TRUE))
    {
        // There was some error with the validation procedure so don't end the dialog.
        return; // Suppress closing dialog
    }

    // OK to save data
    if(!SaveDataToDatabase())
    {
        // Some error
        return;
    }

    // Data validated Ok and was saved to DB OK, so close
    EndDialog(IDOK);
}
```

Unless I miss understand your question.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, that seems like a good solution except that it's not virtual.

Comment: But why does it have to be virtual? You simply state "I don't want the dialog to close if I encounter an error saving the data to the database."

Comment: I don't know what you are proposing. If it was virtual, I could override it and return false if I encounter an error while saving. How else would I use this method to solve the issue?

Comment: Because it returns false if there is an error validating. Thus you don't call `CDialog::OnOK();` and simply return. So your dialog stays open.

Comment: And, if UpdateData returns true, you know you can "SaveData".

Comment: So you're saying to call UpdateData() from my OnOK() handler, and return if it returns false. If it returns true, I save my data. And if that goes okay, I should probably call EndDialog() instead of CDialog::OnOK() to avoid the validation routines from running twice. I guess that should work. I'm not sure how much I like choosing between calling CDialog::OnOK() or having the validation run twice.

Comment: Sure, call EndDialog directly with IDOK to avoid the obsolete validation as it is already been done. I updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems clear MFC wasn't designed to work this way.

But the simplest solution I found was to modify `DoDataExchange()` as follows:

```
void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    // DDX and DDV calls go here

    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
    {
        if (!SaveData())
            pDX->Fail();
    }
}
```

The code above relies on `SaveData()` displaying an error message and returning false if it encounters any errors.

The result is that the regular validation is performed before I attempt to save my data. And, if the code that saves the data fails, I can still prevent the dialog box from closing via the same technique that the MFC validation methods use. (Namely, by calling `pDX->Fail()`).

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say this:

```
// If I save my data here, EndDialog() has already been called
```

All that means is that the `HWND` named `m_hWnd` has been closed and all the child controls with it.  The window is dead, but not your instance of your `CVehicleDlg`.  The member variables associated with the data exchange will have the values from the controls transferred to them.  You should be good to go for saving.

Another approach would be to catch `OnDestroy` in your class instead of `OnOK`.  That way, you get the default processing of `OnOk` to do the data validation.  The window wouldn't be destroyed unless the data validation failed.  You'll have to special case `OnCancel` to set some flag to "not save" when your dialog is destroyed.

Comment: But I don't want the dialog to close if my code that saves the data fails. Similar case with handling `OnDestroy()`: If my save code fails, it's too late to keep the dialog box open.